# Select Data 5 minutes interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have data of 800 different id which is almost 48232 rows. sample data is pasted below

```
 Id        DateTime              Value
 2999   14/11/2022 9:02:43        0.84
 2999   14/11/2022 9:03:14        0.79
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:14       67
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:24       69
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:35       66
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:35       66
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:36       66
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:36       66
 2999   14/11/2022 11:18:24       0.73
 2999   14/11/2022 11:57:36       0.65
 2999   14/11/2022 12:00:22       0.84
 2999   14/11/2022 18:03:12       0.62
 2999   14/11/2022 19:04:27       0.75
 2999   14/11/2022 19:04:54       0.67
 4511   14/11/2022 6:12:43        0.67
 4511   14/11/2022 6:29:42        0.98
 4511   14/11/2022 6:31:05        0.84
 4511   14/11/2022 6:31:10        0.88
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:35       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:36       69
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:59       70
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:59       70
 4511   14/11/2022 16:40:00       70
 4511   14/11/2022 16:40:55       77
 4511   14/11/2022 16:40:56       78
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:00       78
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:56       70
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:56       72
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:58       72
 4511   14/11/2022 16:41:58       72
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:00       71
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:55       67
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:57       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:57       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:59       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:42:59       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:01       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:02       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:03       66
 4511   14/11/2022 16:43:04       66
 4511   14/11/2022 17:03:15       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:03:31       68
 4511   14/11/2022 17:03:33       69
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:00       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:00       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:01       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:01       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:01       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:04:01       67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:14:07       66
```

need to select data after each 5 minutes of specific id. required data sample pasted below

```
  Id        DateTime            Value
 2999   14/11/2022 9:02:43       0.84
 2999   14/11/2022 10:03:14      67
 2999   14/11/2022 11:18:24      0.73
 2999   14/11/2022 11:57:36      0.65
 2999   14/11/2022 18:03:12      0.62
 2999   14/11/2022 19:04:27      0.75
 4511   14/11/2022 6:12:43       0.67
 4511   14/11/2022 6:29:42       0.98
 4511   14/11/2022 16:39:35      66
 4511   14/11/2022 17:03:15      67
 4511   14/11/2022 17:14:07      66
```

using below query to access specific result, need to improve the query performance query take to much time to execute.

```
 WITH rcte AS (
SELECT curr.*
FROM [dbo].[Test] AS curr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[Test]
    WHERE Id= curr.Id AND DateTime< curr.DateTime
)
UNION ALL
SELECT curr.*
FROM rcte AS prev
JOIN [dbo].[Test] AS curr ON prev.Id= curr.Id AND curr.DateTime>= DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, prev.DateTime)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[Test]
    WHERE Id= curr.Id AND DateTime < curr.DateTime AND GpsTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, prev.DateTime)
)
 )
   SELECT *, case when rcte.Value > 0.6 and rcte.Value <=1.5 then 'Accel' 
   when rcte.Value >1.6 and rcte.Value<= 2.5 then 'Brk'
   else 'nthng' end as Vt
   FROM rcte
   ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: is the gap between `rcte.Value <=1.5` and `rcte.Value >1.6` intended? because with this logic you're skipping the value 1.6 itself. Since your question is about performance, you might wanna see [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/) to provide some more needed info.

Comment: Add `CREATE TABLE` DDL including indexes to your question. Your query references column `GpsTime`, which is not in the sample data.

Comment: Your example output data is not on 5-minute intervals and doesn't make sense. E.g. `10:03:14  - 9:02:43 = 1 hour and 31 seconds` e.g. roughly a 5 minutes and 2.5 seconds interval.

Comment: @J.D. related to the ID 2999 the next value that is at least `9:02:43 + 5min` or bigger is `10:03:14`. It took me some time to understand what the OP meant. It's not "data after each 5 minutes of specific id" as the question says, but rather "next data with at least 5 minutes of distance from previous data of same id".